# Content only visible for specific user ID's

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I build something as described above.
I have a user table where every user is identified with a unique ID, and I have a 'friend list' table where User ID's are matched with other User ID's to make a connection. The content table has a TINYINT field called Private, 1 is private & 0 is public. My goal is to make 2 things,

1) Make certain content only visible for users that are on the frienlist
2)Make content only visible for the creator of the content

I'm not sure how I should build this or where to start. Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: Just add the current user id (from session?) in the `WHERE` clause of you queries...

Comment: Assign userlist id(ID's) to content  then make query i-e select * from content-table where friendlist_ids in ( 1,2,3) and content_created_by=take value from session etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query I used:

```
$userContent = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM followlist
JOIN users
on user_id_b = users.id
JOIN board on user_id_a = board.userID
WHERE user_id_a = $userid
AND board.private = 0");
$userContent->execute();
$c = $userContent->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
steps are as follows : 
1. Save the user in the session
2. the things that he can see put them like this
   if(user){
display
}
3. if you have an creator id saved for each content, get the id of the creator

4. check if(creator==content->creator)
{
display
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your view @Exprator, I have the userID trough $_SESSION, I'm trying a few things and will update my question accordingly. I'll keep you updated!